# How to prove that "w will converge to TD fixed point once A is positive definite"

Tags: reinforcement-learning, math, proofs

In *[Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf)* 2nd edition  section 9.4 (p. 206), it says that when we use TD(0) as target and use semi-gradient method to update :

> In general, $w_t$ will be reduced toward zero whenever A is positive definite, meaning >$y^TAy > 0$ for any real vector y $\neq$ 0. Positive definiteness also ensures that the inverse A exists

How to prove this statement? I tried to prove it in the following way, but I can only get  $\lambda <1$ rather than $|\lambda|<1$.

$$
w_{t+1} = (I-\alpha A)w_t + \alpha b \\
\because\delta_{w+1} = (I-\alpha A)\delta_{w}\therefore|\lambda_{max}(I-\alpha A)|\lt 1\Rightarrow\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\delta_{w_t}= 0 \\
(I-\alpha A)y= \lambda y\Rightarrow y^T(I-\alpha A)y= y^Ty-\alpha y^TAy = \lambda y^Ty \\
\Rightarrow 1-\lambda = \alpha\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty}\gt 0\Rightarrow\lambda\lt 1
$$

[image: statement in the book]

Comment: Are you sure it is in section 9.4 (pages 241-247)? I cannot seem to find the statement there.

Comment: The link you post seems to be the first edition of the book. The statement I mentioned can be found in second edition,  p206, 9.4 linear method

Comment: You are right, my previous link was to the "Second edition in progress". I have updated the link to the final 2nd version - could you please accept the edit?